# Windows server 2016 + ODBC MS ACCESS Driver

Tags: node.js, ms-access, odbc, windows-server-2016

So, I have made a Node js project which I host in IIS on a server with windows server 2016. This project is a "reader" of a Ms access database with the aim of exposing some endpoints.
Connecting to odbc is done via https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc.

The problem is that while in windows 10 it works normally, in windows server 2016 when I try to connect I get the error "The operating system is not presently configured to run this application"

Some details:
CONN_STRING: 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=Z:\mydb.accdb'
Edition: Windows Server 2016 Standard 1607